# Polylang non-default language ignores tags in WP_Query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, query-posts, plugin-polylang

I have a mutual DB of custom posts that I'd like different languages to be able to access. If I loop through the post type only, all posts show in all languages, but once I add a tag to the query it only shows on default language page.

The below is displayed with no problems across all pages

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'cars' , 'posts_per_page' => 6) );
```

And this query with tag only shows in default language:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'cars' , 'tag' => 'recommended', 'posts_per_page' => 6) );
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: If the tags is been translated that will be the problem; try to use the correct slug name.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I don't think the tags are getting translated, I have disabled translation for my custom posts.

Comment: Same problem here, did you resolve it in any way?
THKS